# Re-construct dist.Multivariate.Normal rmvn(n,mu,V) function

Tags: r, function, statistics

I need to re-construct the rmvn function from mgcv package.

I mean, I need to create a custom function that does the same as rmvn, where the inputs of the new function must be n (non-negative integer), mu (as a vector) and V (as a positive definite matrix)

Anyone knows where can I start? Or where can I find documentation about this function?

Thank you all

Comment: You can look at the code of the function `mgcv::rmvn` or look at the help page `?mgcv::rmvn` or look at the code of `MASS::mvrnorm`  ... there are may ways to sample.

Comment: I will check. Thank you.

Comment: you're welcome ... another ref: https://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/simulate-multivariate-normal/